# Authorizarion Code Grant with Alexa

Tags: oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, alexa-skills-kit

I am working with **Amazon Alexa** and facing issue with implementing **OAuth2.0 Code Grant** implementation with Alexa

I have successfully implemented the **Implicit Grant** Flow:

1. I have a AWS Lambda function that is responsible for Generation of JWT when user login in my system
2. I have a web server login page (https enabled) from where user can login
3. I have a AWS Lambda function that receive code and generate access_token, refresh_token and end_time
4. I have a API Gateway(post method) that call code grant lambda function (i have not set ant headers because i don't know with Alexa send headers or not)

for implicit grant its working fine

- user select link account from Alexa app
- Alexa shows my login page
- after user login, my page redirect Alexa to provided url along with access_token
- Alexa shows message "linked with skill"

for code grant

- user select link account from Alexa app
- Alexa shows my login page
- after user login, my page redirect Alexa to provided url along with code(i am generating code with JWT)
- Alexa trying to call my code grant link but failing here (not even reaching my lambda i dont know about api gateway)

Comment: hi , re-check your alexa app account linking configuration in developer.amazon( check if you have filled th Access Token URI field and the client secret also check if you have added aws lambra uri in the domain section )

Comment: If you want help debugging the API GW side you would have to provide CW log output.

Comment: @WejdDAGHFOUS i have alredy configured "Access Token URI" and "Client Secret" plus i have also added my "Access Token URI" in domain list
I am calling my lambda from API gateway.